# StatusStrip Labels Text are mirrored

Tags: c#, winforms

I use a `StatusStrip` control which has some `Label` controls. The problem is that sometimes, without any modifications of the code, the text of these labels got mirrored.

The localization of system is right to left because I use the Arabic language, but not all labels has Arabic text.

I changed the following properties:

```
StatusStrip.RightToLeft = Yes;
ToolStripStatusLabel.RightToLeft = Yes;
```

This problem occurs in no logical manner.
I used the Unicode Right-to-left mark, `U+200F` or `\u200f`, but the problem still exists.